# Get all possible value (dropdown options) of a product attribute in Magento

Tags: attributes, product-attribute

I'm trying to display all possible values (dropdown options) of a product in Magento. I'm using the code bellow:

```
    <?php
  $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'display_size'); //"display_size" is my attribute_code
  $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
  foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $id = $instance['value'];
    $value = $instance['label'];
  }
?>
```

but the page doesn't display any results. Any idea?

Thanks, O.

Comment: Looks good to me. Forgot to echo?

Answer (score 0):

You code give `you  all option of attribute ,not given an individual product option`.

If yo want to get a `specific product option and it value then try below`

```
$productObject->getAttributeText('display_size');
```

It given the option label

**for getting option id then try the below**

```
$productObject->getData('display_size');
```

Comment: above code doesn't display anything :(